# How facebook detects my location so precisely only based on IP address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have two-step authentication on facebook. I just tried to log in **from my home PC** but didn't write second step code.
I've got notification that somebody (me) was trying to login to my account and **location was so precise** (within 2 meters).
I wondered how facebook detects location so precisely only based on IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today geolocation is in the core business of Marketing companies, there's a very developped market of customer data, so tons of mobile apps and services collect data such as usual IP addresses, personal information, interests, locations.
That information gets reselled to data brokers, aggregated, corrected. And then Facebook or others can buy that data, merge it, implement corrections and so and get tables for matching IPs and locations that are not public, it seems.
However they offer a high level API to perform market targeting which seems to use that data:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting#location

In your case it was precise because they may have a good dataset based on your privacy settings experience, not only with facebook but with other geo-located apps. In my case their guess is wrong by hundreds of Km, because I was behind a corporate proxy.